# How do I add a CAPTCHA to my PHP form?

Tags: php, forms, captcha

My knowledge of php is not good and I need help.

I have this [php form](http://phpforms.net/php-forms.html) but I don't know how to add a CAPTCHA mechanism.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 10):

I really like [Securimage](http://www.phpcaptcha.org/) is seems to work really well and does not require a third-party external service or javascript (unless you enable the new image feature). Also it can be configured to provide audio captcha for accessibility.

Answer (score 2):

Check this detailed guide about captcha implementation in PHP: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/captcha/